# Autoboxing and void

Tags: java, generics, void, autoboxing

Notice how `Integer.TYPE` and `Integer.class` are both `Class<Integer>`, `Double.TYPE` and `Double.class` are both `Class<Double>`, and how you use autoboxing to convert between between `int` and `Integer` as well as `double` and `Double`.  The question is whether this holds true for `void`: `Void.TYPE` and `Void.class` are both `Class<Void>`, but can you "convert" between `void` and `Void`?

To put it in another way, suppose you have this interface:

```
public interface Foo<T> {
    public T doSomething();
}
```

A class implementing `Foo<Integer>` is free to return an `int` in its implementation of `doSomething()` as the `int` will be boxed.  Similarly for `Foo<Double>` returning `double`.  So, for a `Foo<Void>`: since the only value of `Void` permissible is null (unless you do weird reflection, which is rarely justified), does this mean that you can omit the obligatory `return null`, effectively "boxing" the `Void`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> does this mean that you can omit the obligatory return null, effectively "boxing" the Void?

Nope. This is easy to test for yourself, of course:

```
class Test {
    public Void foo() {
    }
}
```

Compilation gives:

```
Error: Test.java:3: missing return statement
    }
```

... or you could just read the JLS on autoboxing ([section 5.1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)) which doesn't mention `Void` anywhere.